# Constructive interpretation of complete atomic boolean algebras for Stone duality?

Tags: category-theory, boolean-algebra

I read that some magic called Stone duality makes the category of complete atomic boolean algebras and the opposite category of sets equivalent.

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Set#OppositeCategory

I've been interested in a nice way of working with $\text{Set}^{\text{op}}$. I've actually trying to figure out an internal language for it. Directly working with coexponentials and such is really confusing though. So Stone duality sounds super interesting to me.

Can I use Stone duality to get a nice way of talking about $\text{Set}^{\text{op}}$?

There seems to be some weirdness with respect to constructivity though? Perhaps a similar construction works with Heyting Algebras? My theorem prover of choice is Coq if that helps.

Comment: I'm not sure what either "Can I use Stone duality to get a nice way of talking about $\mathsf{Set^{op}}$?" or "There seems to be some weirdness with respect to constructivity though?" is asking exactly, can you clarify?

Comment: That is not quite right - Stone duality says that the category of Boolean algebras is equivalent to the opposite of the category of *Stone spaces*, equivalently *profinite sets*. A different duality says that the category of *complete atomic* Boolean algebras is equivalent to the opposite of the category of sets. These two dualities both restrict to an equivalence between the category of finite Boolean algebras and the opposite of the category of finite sets (since a finite Stone space is discrete, and a finite Boolean algebra is complete and atomic).

Comment: @AlexKruckman So let me know if I'm on the right track here. In my sort of language the category of Locally Cartesian (Closed?) Posets ~ the opposite category of Set. Something to do with presheafs?

Comment: Well, not every Locally Cartesian Closed Poset is a Boolean Algebra!

Comment: You might be interested to know that Stone duality extends to bounded distributive lattice (the [dual spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_theory_for_distributive_lattices) are Priestley spaces, spectral spaces or pairwise Stone spaces) and to Heyting algebras (the [dual spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esakia_duality) are Esakia spaces.)